# realm unique constraint on several fields

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, realm

In Realm ORM, Android.
Is there any way to add unique constraint on two or more fields? Couldn't find it in documentation. 
SQlite example : 
CREATE TABLE a (i INT, j INT, UNIQUE(i, j) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realm currently doesn't support the unique constraint, but it is on our roadmap. Currently the closest is `@PrimaryKey` which has slightly different semantics.

You can follow the feature request here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/967

Comment: Does it support them now?

Comment: And how about now? It's 2019, you know.

Comment: haha... Yeah I checked the original answer date. 2015... Come on haha

Comment: How about now? 2021 and counting... :)

Comment: 2022. Current realm JS version 11rc. Still no unique fields, or mongo-styled unique-indexed-fields.

Comment: +8 years, still no support